# Simpleblobdetector finds way to many keypoints

Tags: c++, visual-studio, opencv, blob, detection

When using OpenCV I would like to find a laserpointer pointed at the ground with live images. Right now, for testing purposes, I am using still images to test the OpenCV algorithm. At the moment I succeeded finding the laser in multiple testimages. Here is my problem. When trying to find the x and y coordinates I get some really strange results. The simpleblobdetector finds around 18*e^many keypoints. Strange, as the image only has a resolution of 640X480 pixels. My code and some output are posted below. Does anyone know why I get so many keypoints and how to fix it, so that I can extract the coordinates?

```
// Read image
Mat im = imread(argv[1], IMREAD_COLOR);
cout << im.cols << "      " << im.rows << endl;
Mat filtered;
inRange(im, Scalar(0, 0, 0), Scalar(255, 255, 216), filtered);
imshow("Filtered image", filtered);


// Simpleblobdetector parameters.
SimpleBlobDetector::Params params;
params.filterByArea = true;
params.filterByCircularity = false;
params.filterByColor = false;
params.filterByConvexity = false;
params.filterByInertia = false;
params.minArea = 50;
params.maxArea = 100;

// Set up the detector with default parameters.
Ptr<SimpleBlobDetector> detector = SimpleBlobDetector::create(params);

// Detect blobs.
std::vector<KeyPoint> keypoints;
detector->detect(filtered, keypoints);
cout << "There are " << keypoints.size() << " BLOBs found." << endl;

// Draw detected blobs as red circles.
// DrawMatchesFlags::DRAW_RICH_KEYPOINTS flag ensures the size of the circle corresponds to the size of blob
Mat im_with_keypoints;
drawKeypoints(im, keypoints, im_with_keypoints, Scalar(0, 0, 255), DrawMatchesFlags::DRAW_RICH_KEYPOINTS);

// De locatie van de keypoints weergeven in de console.
for (int i = 0; i < keypoints.size(); i++)
{
    cout << "The X-cooridnate is: " << keypoints.at(i).pt.x << endl;
    cout << "The Y-coordinate is: " << keypoints.at(i).pt.y << endl;
}

// Show blobs
imshow("keypoints", im_with_keypoints);
waitKey(0);

return 0;
```

This is the ouput:
[image: Without trying to print the coordinates in the console]
[image: With tying to print the BLOB coordinates]

Comment: I had a similar problem. The problem for me was that I linked the wrong library to the Debug-Build and because of that the vector got filled with garbage:
https://stackoverflow.com/questions/49804597/opencv-when-passing-a-stdvector-to-a-function-requirng-a-outputarray-the-vec
Make sure, you linked to the right library(Debug lib to debug build)