# OpenCV: When passing a std::vector to a function requirng a OutputArray, the vec contains garbage

Tags: c++, opencv

I have an issue with the OpenCV(3.1.0) functions that require a OutputArray as parameter.

When I pass a `std::vec` to this parameter, the vector contains garbage or the program even crashes when using the vector later(I suppose OpenCV somehow fills it with wrong memory...). Passing a `cv::Mat` as parameter instead of `std::vec`, it seems to work fine. However it should work with both types as noted in the [example in the documentation](https://docs.opencv.org/3.4.1/d2/de8/group__core__array.html#gaed7df59a3539b4cc0fe5c9c8d7586190).

Here is a simple program with its output. VEC size should be 0, however it is some random value.

```
#include <iostream>
#include <opencv2/opencv.hpp>

int main(int argc, char * argv[]) {

    std::cout << "OpenCV version : " << CV_VERSION << std::endl;

    cv::Mat referenceFrame = cv::Mat::zeros(10, 10, CV_8U);

    std::vector<cv::Point> nonZeroCoordinatesVec;
    cv::Mat nonZeroCoordinatesMat;
    cv::findNonZero(referenceFrame, nonZeroCoordinatesVec);
    cv::findNonZero(referenceFrame, nonZeroCoordinatesMat);

    std::cout << "VEC size: " << nonZeroCoordinatesVec.size() << std::endl;
    std::cout << "MAT size: " << nonZeroCoordinatesMat.total() << std::endl;

    return 0;
}
```

Output:

```
OpenCV version : 3.1.0
VEC size: 18446743853362306490
MAT size: 0
```

It's not only the findNonZero function that fails, but also other ones like finding keypoints with the SimpleBlobDetector.

Compiler used: The one provided with Visual Studio 2017

Comment: What's `std::vec`?

Comment: Are you linking correct libraries? Maybe OpenCV binaries you are using allocate vector differently (e.g. debugs)

Comment: Curious: did you build opencv from source using the same environment you are calling it from? Does it make a difference if you build in Release vs Debug configurations?

Comment: @MFisherKDX It seems to work in release mode! I will double check my linkings to the library! Pretty sure sth is wrong there

Comment: I bet you're linking a debug mode application with release mode OpenCV libraries.

Comment: You are correct! That was it! Wasted so much time for this lol. Thanks!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I linked the Release Libraries to the Debug Build Libraries. Linking the Debug library(world_310d.dll) instead of the Release library(world_310.dll) fixed it.